# Are there enough Wild Artifacts in the game?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I wonder if there are enough Wild Artifacts to find in the game or do I have to buy more than one from Serendipity. 75K gil, if you're not kissed by lady luck, is quite expensive. I think I have found all of them (not bought one yet) but I still have a bunch of portals to open (around 5 locations more to discover).

Does a player who wants to explore all the Historia Crux have to buy more than 1 artifact in order to complete the game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are exactly enough wild artefacts including the ones you can buy from Serendipity to open all the gates. So you will have to spend 75k gil on a artefact.

Comment: Hah! I've just been lucky enough to find that I can buy only one. I'll have to double-check where is that I haven't found the artifact.

Answer (score -2):

From what I'm understanding there are not enough wild artifacts for all the side gates that have to be opened. I'm at the point in the game where it's almost time for the last boss fight and there's only one artifact left to get for the two gates I still need to open (Yaschas massif 100 AF &  The àrchylte steppe ??? AF). I've even bought the only one serendipity has.