# Are there a limited number of artefacts?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Is there a limited number of artefacts, i.e. a limited number of times I can travel to?
If so, should I just be sticking to the main storyline and use the fewest artefacts possible? If I do use a lot of artefacts early on will it affect my endgame?

I'm asking this because the brother of a friend said he was restarting his game because he had messed up with the artefacts.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51564/are-there-enough-wild-artifacts-in-the-game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are in fact, a finite number of artefacts in the game. These are split into two categories:

- `Wild artefacts` - There are only ten of these in game. You can only use them on gates that don't need a specific artefact. If you are stuck finding these, there's a handy guide [here](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-xiii-2/Wild_Artefact_Locations)
- `Regular artefacts` - Each of these correspond to a specific gate and are generally to do with story progression. As you'd expect there is one for each gate. Likewise, you can find a guide to finding these [here](http://segmentnext.com/2012/01/30/final-fantasy-13-2-artifacts-locations-guide/). I wouldn't recommend using this guide though, whereas the wild artefacts can be difficult to find, these are part of the natural story progression and not that difficult to obtain. They're generally awarded as a sort of 'Level Complete' reward

On another note, it is strange that your brother of a friend should restart the game. You can complete the game without locating all of the Wild Artefacts. You will only need them all to collect all 160 fragments, and they don't need to be collected and/or open gates in a specific order.

Comment: Ok so there's a lot more artefacts than needed so i should not have any problem as long as i find a lot of them

Comment: And its also worth noting that the way the wild artifacts are used (the only ones you have choices in) it is impossible to leave yourself in a situation where you have stranded an artifact (ie an artifact behind a artifact locked door) so it doesn't matter what order you use the artifacts in in terms of being able to get them all, etc.

Comment: @Chris `they don't need to be collected and/or open gates in a specific order`

Comment: @BenLefebvre You shouldn't have any problem at all. The only difficulty comes when you're trying to find the last one and you're not sure which one's you've collected.

Comment: Its also not clear but the question implies that you might need an artifact each time you travel. Once an artifact is used on a gate that gate remains unlocked for as much use as you want.

Comment: @Chris Even if you use time reversal? Pretty sure only Wild Gates stay unlocked?

Comment: Cool thanks guys, i'll be able to continue through the story with peace of mind haha

Comment: If you use the close gate ability or whatever its called (not played for a while) then I can't remember what the state of wild gates is but I dont' think I've ever wanted to go through a gate from a rewound zone. Everything I want to do is in that one zone in general...

Comment: @Chris Oh no. But it is possible to replay the game from the very first gate and you would unlock the gates as usual.

Comment: @danRhul: ah, cool. I never thought about doing that. I might have to try it sometime. :)